# How to dual-boot Windows 7 and Windows XP with Windows 7 installed first?

Tags: windows-7, multi-boot, operating-systems

What steps must you take to dual-boot Windows 7 and Windows XP when you have Windows 7 installed first?

Answer (score 3):

See this article : [Install Windows XP in Dual Boot with Pre-Installed Windows 7](http://www.pronetworks.org/forums/install-windows-xp-in-dual-boot-with-pre-installed-windows-7-t104890.html).

It explains in much detail and with many screenshots how to install XP after Win7.

Comment: Dualboot pro is not free software.  I cannot use this method.

Comment: You may be able to do the same with EasyBCD at http://neosmart.net/dl.php?id=1

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, you'll need to install Win XP, then use the Win7 install disk to load up the recovery environment and rebuild the MBR. I would see if you can run x86 XP in XP Mode, it would be easier.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need dual boot you can run Windows XP Applications in XP Mode.
MS uses Virtualization to achieve this.
Details [here](http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/download.aspx)

Comment: My main problem is that I have 64 bit win7 installed and an application I need does not run on 64 bit Windows.  So I planned on installing my old XP back as a dualboot :)

Comment: PS did you mean virtualization, rather than visualization?  Would this not be slower to run memory-intensive apps? :)

Comment: yes, corrected it, I meant virtualization. It will be slightly slow. But it will not make a big diff since this is done in the background by MS, I have run many apps on proper VM on Virtual Server, depending on the RAM you allocate to it, it works well.